# Is it possible to not have a default in QuerySelectField while not allowing blank in the validation?

Tags: python, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I am generating a field with WTForms using a code similar to this:

```
my_field = QuerySelectField(
    'My Field',
    query_factory=lambda: MyClass.query
)
```

But in this case I got back all my elements of type `MyClass` and the first one is automatically selected.

If I change it in this way:

```
my_field = QuerySelectField(
    'My Field',
    query_factory=lambda: MyClass.query,
    allow_blank = True
)
```

The default selection is now empty, which is what I want, but the empty selection is now valid, when instead I want it to be an error.

Is there a way to not have a default but still being able to not make the selection optional?

Answer (score 2):

Adding a `DataRequired` validation to the form for that field would seem the easiest way.

```
from wtforms import validators

my_field = QuerySelectField(
    'My Field',
    query_factory=lambda: MyClass.query,
    allow_blank=True,
    validators=[validators.DataRequired()]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom validator to invalidate the default selection created by `allow_blank = True`.

Using `InputRequired()` or `DataRequired()` would not work because the default "blank" selection has a value of `__None` thus allowing the `my_field` validation to pass.

```
from wtforms.validators import ValidationError

class Form(FlaskForm):
    my_field = QuerySelectField(
        'My Field',
        query_factory=lambda: MyClass.query,
        allow_blank = True
    )

    @staticmethod
    def validate_my_field(self, field):
        if field.data is None:
            raise ValidationError("Please select a value.")
```